# Timezone issue with cron

Tags: cron, time-zone, cronjob

My cron jobs are computed one hour later compared to server time. I don't understand what is going on.

My configuration is the following :

Server time :

```
Europe/Paris
```

In /etc/default/cron I added the following line :

```
TZ="Europe/Paris"
```

Despite that, cron job are launched one hour later than server time. What is really tricky, is that if I ask cron to play instruction "date", it gives the server date (the good one !).

I have no idea of how to resolve this problem ; I've been doing some reading on forums, but found nothing interesting.

What do you think ?

Comment: So cron jobs are being scheduled in UTC.  The Vixie cron man page says, "The daemon will use, if present, the definition from /etc/timezone for the timezone."  What's in `/etc/timezone`?  Have you modified `/etc/timezone` more recently than the `cron` process was started?  Have you tried `/etc/init.d/cron restart`?

Comment: /etc/timezone has been modified recently, without restarting /etc/init.d/cron . I'm gonna try to restart it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Copying my comment as an answer, since it turned out to be the solution; I guessed right.)

So cron jobs are being scheduled in UTC (`Europe/Paris` is at a one hour offset from UTC).

The Vixie cron man page says:

> The daemon will use, if present, the definition from /etc/timezone for
>   the timezone.

What's in `/etc/timezone`? Have you modified `/etc/timezone` more recently than the cron process was started? Have you tried

```
/etc/init.d/cron restart
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Some distros such as Fedora provide a mechanism where you can set `CRON_TZ=` to override your default timezone.

*From the Fedora `man 5 crontab`*

> The  CRON_TZ  variable specifies the time zone specific for the cron
>   table.  The user should enter a time according to the specified time
>   zone into the table.  The time used for writing into a log file is
>   taken from the local  time zone, where the daemon is running.

Something like this:

```
#m  h           d   m   wday    command
CRON_TZ="Europe/Paris"
5   0,6,12,18   *   *   *       /path/to/script.bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says

> Most cron implementations simply interpret crontab entries in the system time zone setting under which the cron daemon itself is run. This can be a source of dispute if a large multiuser machine has users in several time zones, especially if the system default timezone includes the potentially confusing DST. Thus, a cron implementation may special-case any "TZ=" environment variable setting lines in user crontabs, interpreting subsequent crontab entries relative to that timezone

So perhaps your login ID has a TZ setting that differs from the system TZ setting?

Answer (score 1):

Restarting cron was what I needed but for me the command was

```
/etc/init.d/crond restart (crond not cron)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out on Ubuntu 14/16. Worked perfectly for me.

Steps (sudo implied):

1. `cat /etc/timezone`
2. `rm -fv /etc/localtime`
3. `ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime`
4. `apt install -y --reinstall tzdata`
5. `/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart`
6. `tail -f /var/log/syslog`
7. `cat /etc/timezone`

Comment: Where does `cron` get restarted?

Comment: I didn't need to restart cron.